# Material-UI & React: Using the Fade component onScroll

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, css-animations, fade, onscroll

I'm new to using Material-UI. I want to use it's [Fade component](https://material-ui.com/api/fade/) to fade in an element. I'm able to do that like this:

```
<Fade in timeout={3000}>
    <Typography variant="h3" className={classes.h3} gutterBottom>About Me</Typography>
</Fade>
```

The Fade component works properly but executes immediately when the page is loaded. How can I delay the animation until the user scrolls down to where the element is on the page? I don't see any `onScroll` property in the documentation. Does Material-UI provide a way to execute Fade on scroll or would I have to use another library in conjunction with Material-UI?

Comment: Use other conditions (third-party libs for scroll check for example) to set the boolean value of props `in` of `<Fade />` would be fine.

Answer (score 7):

You can utilize `in` property of `Fade` component and only set to true conditionally.

So in your case you need to do something like this -

```
import VizSensor from 'react-visibility-sensor'; // or use any other 3rd party plugin or define your own

function comp=(props) => {

    let [active, setActive] = useState(false);

    return (
        <VizSensor
            onChange={(isVisible) => {
                setActive(isVisible);
            }}
        >
            <Fade in={active} timeout={3000}>
                <Typography variant="h3" className={classes.h3} gutterBottom>About Me</Typography>
            </Fade>
        </VizSensor>
    )

}
```